# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: results.html

Tags: python, scrapy, jinja2

I have run this code on my computer and it works fine. But when I deploy it to zyte, it raises an error.
It seems that it can not reach to the templates and to the sqlite files.

the directory

setup.py

```
# Automatically created by: shub deploy

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name         = 'project',
    version      = '1.0',
    packages     = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {'scrapy': ['settings = gumtree.settings']},
)
```

```
New/   
    .scrapy/crawl_once/gumtree.splite  
    gumtree/              
        __init__.py
        items.py  
        middlewares.py
        models.py
        pipelines.py      
        settings.py       

        spiders/           
            __init__.py
            example.py
    templates/
       base.html
       results.html
    __init__.py
    requirements.txt
    scrapinghub.yml
```

The error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py",line 654, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/app/__main__.egg/gumtree/pipelines.py", line 91, in close_spider
File "/app/__main__.egg/gumtree/pipelines.py", line 123, in send_mail
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 883, in get_template
        return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 857, in _load_template
        template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 117, in load
        source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 199, in get_source
        raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: results.html
```

The code

```py
file_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=file_loader)
template = env.get_template('results.html')
mail_content = template.render(items=self.items)
print(mail_content)
```

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure as well?

Comment: I update it.Can you please check it

Comment: I think your structure is a bit wrong, how can you have two `__init__.py` file in same folder (`gumtree/`)? Can you double check?

Comment: I edited it. Can you check it now?

Comment: Where are you running your `pipeline.py` file? I did a simple test, using your folder structure, there is no issue to run `python gumtree/pipeline.py` within `New` folder.  It throws your error when run `python pipeline.py` within `gumtree` folder.

Comment: Yes. It run perfect in my computer as I mentioned the problem happen when I deploy it to zyte

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the setup.py file. To link it to the template file. I added the setup.py to the question

Comment: I think the problem is in deployment the python packaging does not include templates folder by default (by default the setup.py only includes python code). You can refer to this link to include the templates folder as package data. https://kiwidamien.github.io/making-a-python-package-vi-including-data-files.html Pay attention to the include_package_data key in setup.py file.